# how to write to a file using DSL [Jenkins]?

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I'm presently making a build flow using DSL.

After searching for I while I've been able to find how to read from a text file, but not how to write to one.

Is there a command for it in DSL?

And also I'd take the opportunity to ask where I can find a tutorial or command list for DSL?

Answer (score 1):

Since the DSL is Groovy based I guess you can write any Groovy code and it should work, refer http://grails.asia/groovy-file-examples to get an example of how to write to a file. The DSL commands are provided at https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/ and you can try them out at the playground at http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you cannot use `new File(...).text` for security reasons. You can use [writefile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-writefile-code-write-file-to-workspace) instead:

```
writeFile file: "myfile.txt", text: "File content."
```

Comment: how can I write using %new File(...).text%

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've been able to come up with, it uses writeFile:

```
def readEscape(String file) {
  return readFileFromWorkspace(file).replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"").replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\$", '\\$')
}
def Dockerfile = readEscape('./Dockerfile')
pipelineJob('sample-write-file') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script('''
        pipeline {
          agent any
          stages {
            stage("prep-files") {
              steps {
                writeFile file: './Dockerfile', text: "''' + Dockerfile + '''"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ''')
    }
  }
}
```

The question is unclear about whether the file needs to be written during the processing of the job dsl or during the generated job's execution. Since I needed this for the job execution, that is what my example shows. The file will be read while creating the job and embedded in the created job definition.